# Find the original reference for the theorem on the upper bound of the edge of a cactus.

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, extremal-graph-theory

A graph is a *cactus* if every edge is part of at most one cycle.

A well-known theorem is as follows.

**Theorem 1.** Let $G$ be a cactus. Then $|E(G)|\le \lfloor \frac{3(|V(G)|-1)}{2} 
\rfloor$.

I would like to ask from which formal literature this theorem was originally derived. I want to quote it in my manuscript. So far as I know, it is as an exercise in West's textbook “ D B. West Introduction to Graph Theory [M]. Upper Saddle River: Prentice-Hall, 2001.”.

In addition, are there any **review articles** for this graph class?

Comment: It is fine to cite textbook exercises for this sort of thing. It is also fine to give a one-sentence proof of your own. You don't have to track down the original source.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable comments.  Earlier I was concerned that there would be a problem with citing an exercise directly instead of a theorem in a book.